# Running EJB application client inside app server

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have a rather unusual idea. I want to run a single instance of a Java EE application client inside app server, in a similar way that JMS provider is run/embedded "within" the app server, so that it is started and stopped with the app server. Why? To ease deployment and maintenance of a complex distributed Java EE system which has application client as part of its architecture.

So:

1. There is only one application client on each server where there is app server (Glassfish).
2. I would like to have the application client run in the same start-stop cycle as the application server, and not as a totally separate entity run under a (apache or similar) system service wrapper.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a [custom lifecycle module](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4336/beamc?a=view) would do the trick?

Comment: Good idea, I need to see will it support all I need. The problem with this idea is that, from what I know, it will run code INSIDE the app server, which defeats the purpose of application client, and I do need it since I have resources that app server cannot pool so it is not per JEE paradigm to use these resources directly from app server.

Answer (score 1):

> To ease deployment and maintenance of
>   a complex distributed Java EE system which
>   has application client as part of its
>   architecture.

I don't get your idea. But if you want to ease the deployment and maintenance, use rather **Java Web Start** to deploy the client application. This will simplify the deployment issue a lot. This is supported by Glassfish.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887806/difference-between-an-application-client-and-a-stand-alone-client).

Comment: This is not applicable in my case, I don't have physical users, but the application client is used to overcome some JEE issues, so it wouldn't work. But thank you for reply.